# Prove the function is continuous in $\Bbb R^2$ \ {(0,0)}

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I calculated the iterated limits of the function. They are -1 and 1. Since the limits are not the same, does that prove that the function is not continuous at (0,0)? Or do i have to do more stuff?

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}\frac {x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}&(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\k& (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$

Also, there's another exercise where they give k=1 and ask to calculate the partial derivative in x at (0,0). Why do I need k=1?

Comment: There is only one limit.  If you have different limits following different contours at the same point, that is sufficient to say that the limit does not exist. (and the function is not continuous.)

Comment: Calculating $f_x$ at $(0,0)$ is the same as calculating the derivative of $g(x)=f(x,0)$ at $x=0$, right?  You need $k=1$ for continuity at $0$.

Comment: That function satisfies the title, no matter what $k$ is. I think you need to retitle the question.

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}\frac {x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}&(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\k& (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

is not continuous at $(0,0)$ because the limit does not exist at that point.

You have shown this fact by approaching $(0,0)$ from different directions and having different limits.

For partial derivative you need the value of your function at $(0,0)$ to find the limit of the difference quotient so they gave you $k=1$ to use it  in order to find the partial derivative.